# Separate Spam and Ham for WordCloud Visualization

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join, spam-prevention, word-cloud

I am performing spam detection and want to visualize spam and ham keywords separately in Wordcloud. Here's my .csv file.

```
data = pd.read_csv("spam.csv",encoding='latin-1')
data = data.rename(columns = {"v1":"label", "v2":"message"})
data = data.replace({"spam":"1","ham":"0"})
```

[image: data.head()]

Here's my code for WordCloud. I need help with spam_words. I cannot generate the right graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud 

spam_words = ' '.join(list(data[data['label'] == 1 ]['message']))
spam_wc = WordCloud(width = 512, height = 512).generate(spam_words)

plt.figure(figsize = (10,8), facecolor = 'k')
plt.imshow(spam_wc)
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Specifically what is wrong with your current output? Also, you posted the names of your csv files, but it would help if you posted the first few lines of the actual data.

Comment: Hello @Peter, I want the spam_words variable to only take in messages that were labelled spam. Currently, it is taking in all the messages and showing me a combined wordcloud of spam and ham.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I would like to know if you need more information about the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the current code replaces `"spam"` and `"ham"` with the one-character *strings* `"1"` and `"0"`, but you filter the DataFrame based on comparison with the *integer* 1. Change the replace line to this:

```
data = data.replace({"spam": 1, "ham": 0})
```